# Class not found on path: DexPathList exception , i am using two module dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse

here is the logcat message

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{mypackage.SplScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mypackage.SplScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mypackage-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/mypackage-2, /system/lib]]`